# Extract frames from video FFMPEG with frameskip and name it accordingly.\

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to extract every 5th frame from a video and rename it accordingly.

```
frame_0000.jpg
frame_0005.jpg
frame_0010.jpg
frame_0015.jpg
```

Are there any parameters in the ffmpeg command other than the framerate and FPS to do so. Current command generates output sequentially.

```
ffmpeg -i foo.avi -r 1 -s WxH -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a recent ffmpeg build, run

```
ffmpeg -i foo.avi -vf "setpts=N/TB,fps=1,select='not(mod(n\,5))',scale=WxH" -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 -f image2 foo-%03d.jpeg
```